# How to configure ubuntu server with LDAP group based authentication

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, openldap

By installing libnss-ldap we are able to integrate an Ubuntu server with ldap (openldap). But we are unable to configure ldap group based authentication.

We need to configure in such a way that user from a particular group need only to login.

Please let me know is it possible configure it and please update us the steps or any url.

Thanks

Geo

Answer (score 1):

You can configure detailed access rules in `/etc/security/access.conf` - read the file, it tells you what you need.

Note however that this only works if your group mappings are correct from LDAP. To check if this is the case, use `getent group`.

Comment: Its working fine...In addtion to that done th folloing:Edit /etc/pam.d/sshd and uncomment

account  required     pam_access.so

Answer (score 0):

The same question I found in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52169711/ssh-access-to-specific-ldap-group), and it is work for me.

The following setting are snippets from stackoverflow post.

1. `vim /etc/pam.d/sshd`

   ```
   account  required     pam_access.so
   ```
2. vim `/etc/security/access.conf`

   ```
   +:root:ALL
   +:localuser:ALL
   +:mygroup:ALL
   -:ALL:ALL
   ```